# Php: how to make variables work in mysql instructions

Tags: php, mysql, variables, authentication

i am trying to make a last online system and this is the code that (should) run after the login

```
$name = $user['username']
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE username = $name");
    $message = "Connected";
```

normally, If i type this code in php tags the name is displayed

```
   echo $user['username']
```

but it seems that this variable in the mysql_query doesn't work

why?
how should I set "$name" to make it work?

Comment: Quote and escape your input.

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` - that will tell you what the problem is. You can also echo out your query and see what happens when you run it directly in the database.

Comment: Everyone is telling you to quote your variables, but better still is to learn to properly use prepared statements so that you are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use quotes in `'$name'`.
Try:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE username = '$name'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your variables

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE username = '$name'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to quote a string in a mysql query so your query should be

```
"UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE username = \"$name\""
```

However I would still caution against direct query manipulation like this for many reasons. Have you looked into using a library like PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php?

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the query with the variable like

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE username = '" . $name . "');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself using another variable
with this code in index.php everything worked :)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = now() WHERE uid = {$user['uid']}");
```